# Maximum allowed values in a single sharepoint lookup column/ sharepoint list update

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, lookup-column

I am facing problem with my custom developed webpart which inserts data into a sharepoint list using excel sheet. I have a list with around 50+ columns in it, it has 10+ lookup columns in it, things working fine with less number of records (till 470 values for a single lookup column) but what I observed is when my lookup column is having more than 470 values in a single lookup column its throwing some error while trying to update listitem using listitem.update method. In event viewer what I found is : Unknown SQL Exception 8003 occurred. Additional error information from SQL Server is included below.
"The incoming tabular data stream (TDS) remote procedure call (RPC) protocol stream is incorrect. Too many parameters were provided in this RPC request. The maximum is 2100."

Now when i try editing some lookup item in list having 470 values for a single lookup column, and try adding some more values gets the error message: : "Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904" with the above mentioned message in event viewer logs.
Anyone aware about the maximum allowed values for a single lookup column in sharepoint list? and how can i update if it is possible with some configuration? any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're running into the same problem as described in [SharePoint 2010 Managed Metadata Column limitation – Error 81020030](http://kellydjones.com/archive/2011/05/22/145485.aspx), due to the way SharePoint saves the listitem to the SQL server there is a limitation on the number of values which can be in the listitem.

The way the limit is reached isn't documented anywhere and seems to be a listitem wide limit.

The 2100 parameters limit to a stored procedure is a [SQL server limit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx) which can't be changed.