# How to allow users to select multiple answers from a dropdown box?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

While the most logical solution to this would be to make checkboxes for the answers, there are over 1000 possible choices, so while I want them to be able to select multiple options, putting 1000 checkboxes on the survey would look terrible and be hard to navigate.

Is there a way that I can set it up so that they can select an unlimited number of responses to a question via a huge dropdown list?

I could make the answer a freeform textbox but I want the ability to track (similar) answers among users, which I cannot rely on if they are allowed to choose their own syntax.

Comment: Have you considered making a selection from a dropdownlist and add the selected item into a gridview or something?

Answer (score 2):

You could try using a multi lookup:

[image]

That way you could even easily track all your answers which would be stored in a list.

Comment: Good idea, however SharePoint do have limitations when it comes down to lookup column of any kind. Or to be correct, more a limit in SQL. http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/37098/maximum-allowed-values-in-a-single-sharepoint-lookup-column-sharepoint-list-upd

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways how you can approach this. A multi lookup, like Paul suggested, would be the most comfortable.

If you really need a dropdown field and are able to use InfoPath, you can create a button, which copies the values of the drop-down field into a text box. Get this behaviour with Action -> Set a fields value and add a formula like `concat(text field; drop-down field; "; ")`. Then your text field would look something like `Option A; Option J; Option F;`.

Answer (score 0):

Is using the term store an option? 
You could create a term set in the term store with all of your values. For your list, create a managed metadata column that points to that term set. When a applicable values or click the tag icon to show all potential values.